# Reading matplotlib graphs from file

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to read (say) 4 .jpeg graphs produced by `matplotlib` into `matplotlib` again so that they can be replotted as subplots? If so, how would I do it?

Comment: Yes that is possible. But that is somehow the worst of all possible ways of producing subplots. Before someone answers that question, can you either confirm that you really want to do that, or provide more information about why you would need such a hack?

Comment: If you mean reading the picture to do some modifications,I don't think it can do this.If you want to insert a image,you can check out [figimage](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.figimage) or [annotation box](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/demo_annotation_box.html)

Comment: Yes, I realize it would be easier to modify the plot generation code, but I was more just interested to see if it could be done - Python has easy ways to do so many things after all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do it by reading jpeg files of existing plots (noting the comments), one way might be to read in the graphs in with `scipy.misc.imread`. I've set the axis labels off assuming you saved the original graphs with labels and everything.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import imread

# Create a figure with 2x2 arranged subplots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)

# Plot images one by one here
# (Just using the same jpeg file in this example...)
im1 = imread("graph1.jpg")
ax[0,0].imshow(im1)
ax[0,0].axis('off')

ax[0,1].imshow(im1)
ax[0,1].axis('off')

ax[1,0].imshow(im1)
ax[1,0].axis('off')

ax[1,1].imshow(im1)
ax[1,1].axis('off')

fig.show()
```

[image]